# Omniauth provider locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, locale, omniauth

I use Devise with Omniauth to let users log in through their Facebook and Google accounts. However I have one problem...

If I want to change the name of the provider, ie. `Google Oauth2` to `Google`. How can I achieve this on buttons and other sign in forms?

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to image_tag('facebook-login.png',:size=>'30x30'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>

<%= link_to image_tag('google-plus-logo.png',:size=>'30x30'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2) %>

<%= link_to image_tag('twitter-login.png',:size=>'30x30'), user_omniauth_authorize_path(:twitter) %>
```